# GoogleMap showing Custom Infowindow twice- one Inside Other

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am loading a GoogleMap with marker and InfoWindow. But My Info window coming twice (one default and one the image which I used as background of my xml.[image])as the attached image. I have to use my custom 9 patch background for this. I am adding my code which I have used for this. Please check and lease guide me what I am doing wrong.

My CustomInfoWindow class.

```
 public class CustomInfoWindow implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    TextView mTxtTitle;
    TextView mTxtAddress;
    TextView mTxtNavigation;

    public CustomInfoWindow(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
        View rootView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
        mTxtTitle= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_window_title);
        mTxtAddress= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_window_address);
        mTxtNavigation= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_window_nav_icon);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

xml file which I am inflating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/info_window"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin30"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.ishippo.shipper.customviews.TextViewBold
            android:id="@+id/txt_window_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pickup_loc_title"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <com.ishippo.shipper.customviews.TextViewBold
            android:id="@+id/txt_window_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin5"
            android:text="@string/pickup_loc_title"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/height1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin20"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin20"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_window_address"
        android:background="@color/hint_color" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin20"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.ishippo.shipper.customviews.TextViewBold
            android:id="@+id/txt_window_nav_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/navigate"
            android:text="@string/navigate"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I am calling adding the window by below code:

```
mGmap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindow(getActivity()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kinda old question, but all you have to do is to replace your getInfoWindow() and getInfoContents() methods.

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
    View rootView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
    mTxtTitle= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_window_title);
    mTxtAddress= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_window_address);
    mTxtNavigation= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_window_nav_icon);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}
```